# SWIFT 4 Save custom class locally without NS Coding

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4, nsuserdefaults

I want to save the latest Notifications a user has received so when he opens the app later again, its not empty until it has loaded them again.

For that I have custom classes which do not to use NSCODING.

```
class UserModel {
var email:String?
var profileImageUrl: String?
var username: String?
var id: String?

}

extension UserModel {
static func transformUserInfo(dict: [String:Any], key : String) -> UserModel {
    let user = UserModel()

    user.email = dict["email"] as? String
    user.profileImageUrl = dict["profileImageUrl"] as? String
    user.username = dict["username"] as? String
    user.profilText = dict["profilText"] as? String

    return user
}
}
```

they are shortened for no overkill in information.

Now I want to save them and tried with user defaults but to no success yet.

```
//            self.defaults.setValue(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.savedUsers), forKey: "savedUsers")
//
//            self.defaults.setValue(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.savedNoti), forKey: "savedNoti")
//            self.defaults.synchronize()
```

I tried this before from other threads to no success.

my saved users

```
    var savedUsers = [UserModel]()
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Read up on [`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable).

Comment: I tried and came to no working result

Comment: Update your question with what you tried and clearly explain what issues you are having.

Comment: Please see the link I posted. `Codable` has nothing to do with `NSCoding` or `NSKeyedArchiver`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `Codable`

```
class UserModel : Codable {
  var email:String?
  var profileImageUrl: String?
  var username: String?
  var id: String?
}
```

//

```
do {
     let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(yourModels) // convert array to data
     let models = try  JSONDecoder().decode([UserModel].self, from: data) // convert data to array
}
catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Comment: You probably want ProprtyListEncoder/Decoder, not JSON.

Comment: so i am able to save them and retrieve them but when I open my vc I want them to be showed. Currently I have to refresh the tableview then the saved notifications are shown correctly. Its like it needs 1-2 seconds to load them even though they are saved in user defaults?